# Is there any way to stop / reverse aging

Tags: vedas

I once saw a video of sadguru, he mentioned that during one sadna he made a mistake and he stated to age extremely fast and after he found out he was aging very fast he did some other mantra jaap/ sadhna to slow down his aging and even reverse his aging.

So My question is, do u guys know any such ways of mantra/ sadhna

Ps - i m 22 just Outta curiosity

Comment: are you sure?  you want to become a baby again?

Comment: Well after all these cases of cardiac arrest and heart attack of very young people i wanted to know more about keeping body healthy and young 